# Get User's Home Phone from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My calls to the API to get users work just fine, but the default URL does not return the home phone number, or the ip phone number.

```
/Users/jo.bloggs@example.com
```

adding parameters works for other things

```
/Users/jo.bloggs@example.com/?$select=id,displayName,mail,postalCode,businessPhones
```

works too, I have tried homephone, homephones, homePhone, homePhones and ipphone, ipphones, ipPhone, ipPhones but do not get those properties returned. We can see the properties filled in on our local Active Directory, so they are in there.

Looking at the docs I don't see mention of home or ip phones https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0 but I am hoping I am missing something.

Comment: Part of the goal of posting this is to get the attention of a MS user that can add the feature, or explain its absence, they have done that around here for other things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some attributes (such as ipPhone) that are synchronized by default might not be exposed using the Microsoft Graph API. In these cases, you can use the [Azure AD Connect directory extension feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/user-provisioning-sync-attributes-for-mapping#sync-an-attribute) to synchronize the attribute to Azure AD.

Comment: thanks that helped. For some reason the fieldname ipPhone does not work, only a prefixed version with a 33 character hash in it extension_<33chars>_ipPhone. I don't have direct access to the system, but have been told its been done correctly, so it works enough for us.

Comment: @CodeMonkey - do you include it just like you put it above in your $select?  Replacing the 33 chars specific to your org obviously.

Comment: @MikeDevenney - yes, also added another answer to be clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

To extend on my comment

> For some reason the fieldname ipPhone does not work, only a prefixed
> version with a 33 character hash in it extension_<33chars>_ipPhone. I
> don't have direct access to the system, but have been told its been
> done correctly, so it works enough for us

The URL path we have is now:

/Users/user.name@example.com/?$select=id,displayName,mail,homePhone,mobilePhone,businessPhones,ipPhone,profile,streetAddress,postalCode,extension_e48de7ec5b11c947e3006271ff83029_ipPhone,extension_e48de7ec5b11c947e3006271ff83029_homePhone

The codes for both of our fields fields are the same.

I presume the codes for other orgs will be different, but just in case I have not used our actual ones here.

Comment: Are the codes the same across all extension fields or different for each one?

Comment: @MikeDevenney appear to be the same, updated answer to clarify